# SQLJocky: Incorrect encoding of received text

Tags: mysql, encoding, unicode, dart, cyrillic

I've implemented simple web server to have proxy to MySQL using 'sqljocky' package.
And I have issue with character encoding, cyrillic glyphs displays incorrectly:

```
ÐÐ°Ð²ÑÐ´Ð¾Ð² ÐÐ¸ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¸Ð¹ instead of Давыдов Витайлий
```

**EDIT**: Table collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

I've tried to query `SET NAMES UTF8`:

```
pool.query('set names utf8');
```

[**UPDATED**] Then I've created my.cnf in /etc/ directory with this content:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Output of `show variables like "%char%";`

```
mysql> show variables like "%char%";
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Output of `show variables like 'collation%'`

```
mysql>  show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

But still having incorrect displayed characters.

How to get it displayed correctly?

Comment: Tables in your database uses `utf_general_ci` charset? Looks like the problem with charset of tables.

Comment: It uses `utf8_general_ci` charset

Comment: mysql> show variables like 'collation%';

Comment: @mezoni, updated information, there are strange values %)

Comment: Finally configured MySQL, but still have no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in sqljocky which meant that unicode characters weren't being encoded properly. I have fixed some of the places where the bug was occurring in v0.5.5 which I have just published. When I have more time I will make sure that it is fixed everywhere.

Comment: James, now app fails with error. Opened new [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues/22)

Comment: Confirm, after SDK and sqljocky update characters displays correctly.